# File contents are copied again and again, ansible is not acting as idempotent

Tags: ansible, idempotent

Im trying to add file contents into remote nodes, below script is working but problem is If I run it again the file contents are copied again and again to remote nodes, ansible is not acting as idempotent.Any suggestions will be appreciated

```yaml
    hosts: all
    vars:
       content: "{{ lookup('file','/etc/foo.txt')}}"
    tasks:
      - name: finding all files present in directory
        find:
          paths: /etc/something.d/
          file_type: file
          patterns: '*.d'
        register: c1
        become: true
      - lineinfile:
          path: "{{ item.path }}"
          line: "{{ contents }}"
          state: present
          create: yes
          backup: yes
        register: c2
        become: true
        with_items: "{{ c1.files }}"
      - debug:
          var: c1
      - debug:
          var: c2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lineinfile task is behaving as documented since you did neither specify the parameter `regexp` nor `search_string`.

Since we do not know whether the file you read might contain a regular expression, better use search_string as it can just contain the same line again.

```
- lineinfile:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      line: "{{ contents }}"
      search_string: "{{ contents }}"
      state: present
      create: yes
      backup: yes
    register: c2
    become: true
    with_items: "{{ c1.files }}"
```

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html: